# Extracting text from a JSON file into specified output using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON text file from Qualitrics that looks like this (for example, this is one variable I pulled from the text):

```
{
      "SurveyID": "SV_8v79iA9BlgTnAnH",
      "Element": "SQ",
      "PrimaryAttribute": "QID7",
      "SecondaryAttribute": "Do you use similar websites or resources to accomplish the objectives you have in using Open Data...",
      "TertiaryAttribute": null,
      "Payload": {
        "QuestionText": "Do you use similar websites or resources to accomplish the objectives you have in using Open Data Flint?",
        "DefaultChoices": false,
        "DataExportTag": "Similar",
        "QuestionID": "QID7",
        "QuestionType": "MC",
        "Selector": "SAVR",
        "SubSelector": "TX",
        "DataVisibility": {
          "Private": false,
          "Hidden": false
        },
        "Configuration": {
          "QuestionDescriptionOption": "UseText"
        },
        "QuestionDescription": "Do you use similar websites or resources to accomplish the objectives you have in using Open Data...",
        "Choices": {
          "1": {
            "Display": "Yes"
          },
          "2": {
            "Display": "No"
          }
        },
        "ChoiceOrder": [
          1,
          2
        ],
        "Validation": {
          "Settings": {
            "ForceResponse": "ON",
            "ForceResponseType": "ON",
            "Type": "None"
          }
        },
        "GradingData": [],
        "Language": [],
        "NextChoiceId": 3,
        "NextAnswerId": 1
      }
    }
```

I want to extract text only from lines `QuestionText` and `QuestionID` so that it creates an output that looks exactly like this:

```
*
name = QID7
text = 
Do you use similar websites or resources to accomplish the objectives you have in using Open Data Flint?                          
*
```

Here is my code so far but I'm getting an error that the list indices must be integers or slices, not str:

```
import json

with open('flint.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# parse file
obj = json.loads(data)

print("name = " + str(obj["SurveyElements"]["Payload"]["QuestionID"]), "text = " + str(obj["SurveyElements"]["Payload"]["QuestionText"]))
```

How can I create a Python script that will extract the information I want and output the results in the format I need so that the asterisks, 'name =', 'text =', line breaks, and clean text replicate the above output? Will I need to use regex to get what I need? Or apply multiple conditions per line until the conditions are satisfied?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fca0998024c3> in <module>
----> 1 print("name = " + str(obj["QuestionID"]), "text = " + str(obj["QuestionText"]))

KeyError: 'QuestionID'

Comment: Can you post the full structure of `obj`?  
You referenced `obj["SurveyElements"]`, but that **key** is not present in what you provided as the sample data.

Comment: I uploaded the full structure to google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bswVuwMrwsNDY2q486_R_IPz5njfAGCe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely helped that you eventually added the structure of the json file.

After looking at your approach, I would just note that you need to account for the survey elements being in a list of dictionaries.

Below is an example to get what you want.  I did assume you are only looking at survey questions, which is why I included the check: `if element["Element"] == "SQ"`  (only these elements include `QuestionID` & `QuestionText`)

```
import json

# open json file
with open('flint.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

# load json
obj = json.loads(data)

# create a list of dictionaries,
# that contains only the survey elements
survey_elements_list = obj["SurveyElements"]

# iterate through the list
# and only look at survey questions
# checking if element["Element"] == "SQ"
for element in survey_elements_list:
    if element["Element"] == "SQ":
        question_id = element["Payload"]["QuestionID"]
        question_text = element["Payload"]["QuestionText"]
        print("*")
        print(f"name = {question_id}")
        print(f"text =\n{question_text}")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `QuestionText` and `QuestionID` fields are nested within the `Payload` dictionary. You need to index into that dictonary before accessing those fields.

Your print should look like the following:

```py
print(f"name = {obj["Payload"]["QuestionID"]}, text = {str(obj["Payload"]["QuestionText"]}")
```

**Edit:** The full JSON file shows more layers of nesting that we need to go through to access a specific field. Accessing these fields uses roughly the same format as above, but with a couple extra index accesses (I've also edited the response to use format-strings, rather than string concatenation):

```py
for survey_element in obj["SurveyElements"]:
    survey_element_payload = survey_element["Payload"]
    if "QuestionID" in survey_element_payload and "QuestionText" in survey_element_payload:
        print(f"name = {survey_elements_payload["QuestionID"]}, text = {survey_elements_payload["QuestionText"]}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm getting the same error but with 'Payload' instead. Might it have something to do with the way I'm parsing the file?

Comment: Does the text file start with `[` and end with `]`?

Comment: I uploaded the full text file to google drive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bswVuwMrwsNDY2q486_R_IPz5njfAGCe/view

Comment: Edited. In the future, please post the entire JSON file -- the schema you've described in the original post is different from the one in the file. By posting a schema different from the original, you're essentially asking people to solve a problem different from the one you're currently facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an alternate solution here, but it might be better to use `str.format` for this actually, as shown below. Note that the variable `json_string` contains the same text contents from the original question above.

```py
import json

json_string = """
{REPLACE CONTENTS}
"""

desired_format = """\
*
name = {QuestionID}
text =
{QuestionText}
*\
"""

# Load JSON string to a Python `dict` object
obj = json.loads(json_string)

# Print formatted string using keyword arguments from "Payload" object
print(desired_format.format(**obj["Payload"]))
```

If you want to, you can even pass (unnamed) positional arguments instead to the format-string, here's how:

```py
desired_format = """\
*
name = {}
text =
{}
*\
"""

obj = json.loads(json_string)

print(desired_format.format(obj['Payload']['QuestionID'], 
                            obj['Payload']['QuestionText']))
```

Output:

```
*
name = QID7
text =
Do you use similar websites or resources to accomplish the objectives you have in using Open Data Flint?
*
```